# Java ArrayList incompatible types

Tags: java, collections

i have a problem . I'm trying to add and them retrieve objects of the same class to ArrayList , but when i try to retrieve them i get incompatible types erroe

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

Test(){
    main();
}

List test = new ArrayList();

public void main(){
    test.add(new Square(10));

    Iterator i = test.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Square temp = i.next();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - you're not using generics anywhere, so `i.next();` is just returning `Object` as far as the compiler is concerned.

Options:

- Use generics
- Cast to `Square`:

  ```
  Square temp = (Square) i.next();
  ```

Personally I'd favour using generics - it's much nicer to have type safety where you can :)

```
// Not clear why this is an instance variable - and please make fields private :)
List<Square> test = new ArrayList<Square>();

public void main() {
    test.add(new Square(10));

    Iterator<Square> i = test.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Square temp = i.next();
        // Use square here
    }
}
```

Two asides:

- The enhanced `for` loop can replace your while loop:

  ```
  for (Square square : test)
  ```
- It's odd to have an *instance* method called `main` with no parameters; it's more common to have `public static void main(String[] args)`. There's nothing illegal about what you've done here, just odd.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) type `List<Square>`, `ArrayList<Square>` and `Iterator<Square>` to avoid this.

If you don't the compiler cannot "know" what is the actual types of elements in `test`, and it "thinks" them as of type `Object`.

```
List<Square> test = new ArrayList<Square>();
public void main(){
    test.add(new Square(10));

    Iterator<Square> i = test.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Square temp = i.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast to `Square`:

```
while(i.hasNext()){
    Square temp = (Square) i.next();
}
```

The iterator will return `Object` type elements only.

With Java 1.5+ and *generics*, we can do it without casting:

```
// a list, that will only accept Square instances
List<Square> test = new ArrayList<Square>();

public void main(){
    test.add(new Square(10));

    Iterator<Square> i = test.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Square temp = i.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think that the downvoter *might* have only seen an earlier version of your answer - where you only mentioned the casting issue, and not the using generics alternative..

Comment: eErr, no. That was not the case. And I consider the generics hint as a bonus info anyway - a simple cast perfectly solves the problem

Comment: @Andreas_D: My answer has been downvoted too. Unclear why. (Although I would say an answer which *just* had the cast would be somewhat unhelpful, as it would only be helping to solve the problem for the single line, instead of addressing the much broader point.)

Comment: Though I agree with @JonSkeet: about the previous version, this version of the answer seems helpful to me. +1 for both answers from me

Comment: @Jon - I've seen the downvote. Strange. But I don't agree on the other thought. The only problem was, that Sysel didn't know, that a *normal* iterator will return `Object` type objects only and that we need to cast to solve *incompatibel type* issues.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Yes, that would have solved his immediate issue - and still left him writing nasty code. Using generics is by far the better approach. It's like answering someone who wants to know how to escape quotes in SQL values by just doing that, and not explaining parameterized queries instead...