# incompatible types when trying to make random in java

Tags: java

**Error:**

```
error: incompatible types
```

**Question:** What do I have to change or add to my code to make this work?

**This line:**

```
kies KiesNaam = lijst.get( n );
```

**Class:**

```
class kies extends OnthoudNaam implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size() );
        kies KiesNaam = lijst.get( n );
        textvak2.setText("" + KiesNaam );
    }
}
```

**The whole code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

// Main method to make the frame
public class Loterij3 extends JFrame {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    JFrame frame = new Loterij3();
    frame.setExtendedState( frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "My Lottery!" );
    frame.setContentPane( new Paneel() );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
}

class Paneel extends JPanel {
private boven boven;
JTextArea textvak1;
JTextField textvak2;
OnthoudNaam onthoudNaam = new OnthoudNaam();
JTextField invoervak1;

public Paneel() {
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // using border Layout.
setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

boven = new boven(); 

textvak1 = new JTextArea();
add( new JScrollPane( textvak1 ) );
textvak1.setBackground( Color.WHITE );

textvak2 = new JTextField();
textvak2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
textvak2.setEditable( false );  

add( boven, BorderLayout.NORTH );
add( textvak1, BorderLayout.CENTER );
add( textvak2, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
}


public class boven extends JPanel {
JButton kiesWin, resetL;
JLabel label1;

public boven() {
    setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
    setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 4, 100, 5 ) ); // using GridLayout.
    Border border = 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
    setBorder( border );

    kiesWin = new JButton("Kies een Winnaar!");
    kiesWin.addActionListener( new kies() );
    resetL = new JButton("Reset alles");
    resetL.addActionListener( new reset() );
    label1 = new JLabel("Voer Persoon in en druk op enter: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    invoervak1 = new JTextField( 20 );
    invoervak1.addActionListener( new InvoerVakHandler() );

    add( label1 );
    add( invoervak1 );
    add( kiesWin );
    add( resetL );
    }
}

// de naam
class naam {
    private String ingevoerdNaam;

    public naam( String ingevoerdNaam) {
        this.ingevoerdNaam = ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String getIngevoerdNaam() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }
}

// Arraylist
class OnthoudNaam extends JPanel {
    protected ArrayList<naam> lijst;

    public OnthoudNaam() {
        lijst = new ArrayList<naam>();
        }

        public void voegNaamToe(naam x ) {
        lijst.add(x);
        }

        public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(naam x : lijst ) {
        buffer.append( x );
        buffer.append( "\n" );
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
}

// invoer handler
public class InvoerVakHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        String invoer = invoervak1.getText();
        naam naam = new naam( invoer );
        onthoudNaam.voegNaamToe( naam );
        textvak1.setText( onthoudNaam.toString() );
        invoervak1.setText( "" );
    }
}
    // kies
class kies extends OnthoudNaam implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size() );
        kies KiesNaam = lijst.get( n );
        textvak2.setText("" + KiesNaam );
    }
}

// reset
class reset implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    }
}
}
```

**For everyone who is trying to help me: Thank you for all your help and patience in advance!**

Comment: what's lijst? Is that a list that holds type kies?

Comment: `lijst` is a `ArrayList<naam>`, as you can see in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447597/java-error-cannot-find-symbol-and-cant-figure-out-why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447597/java-error-cannot-find-symbol-and-cant-figure-out-why) or one of the other 4 last questions of the OP.

Comment: Is KiesNaam a class? If yes try to change return type to `KiesNaam` and replace `kies KiesNaam = lijst.get( n );` by `KiesNaam kies = lijst.get( n );`

Comment: if lijst is a an ArrayList containining naam objects, then calling get() on that list will return a naam object. You're trying to put a naam object into a kies reference. The only thing you can put into a kies reference is an instance of kies, or something that extends kies.

Comment: @Aubin: No, OP is not following naming conventions at all...

Comment: Very readable ;) Which type lijst list holds? you need to declare the list with correct type. that's why java has generics. this question asked a few times. try these 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712628/why-does-an-incompatible-types-compile-error-turn-into-a-warning-when-a-class
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290942/java-arraylist-incompatible-types

Comment: try kies KiesNaam = lijst[n]

Comment: Robert C Martin's head just exploded lol :D (all kidding aside, you should really consider putting some emphasis on improving the readability of your code.)

Comment: For future reference, it would be better to follow typical java naming conventions, as this would make it easier for others to read and understand your code. An example of this is that class names start with a capital letter (eg. ActionEvent), while references to objects should start with a lower case letter. (eg. the "r" in Random r = new Random()). Reversing this naming convention (eg. kies KiesNaam = lijst.get( n )) adds confusion, especially later on in the code where you end up using your variables.

Comment: just aded the whole code, tried kies KiesNaam = lijst[n] but then i get an error at the same line cannot find symbol

Comment: @DimitriDuvanskij Please accept answers to your previous questions if you find the answers useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is of type `ArrayList<naam>` but you're trying to assign a value in it (which will be of type `naam`) to a variable of type `kies`.

A few pointers to improve the readability of your code:

- Follow Java naming conventions. Use camelCase. Classes should start with a capital letter (example MyClassName). Variables should start with a lowercase letter (example myClassInstance).
- Use the interface over the concrete type. So your list should be `List<Naam>`. This lets you switch out implementations later, if you need to.
- User proper and consistent indentation.

Comment: my list is of the type naam and i'm trying to assign it to a type kies. so i should change the code to naam KiesNaam = lijst( n );?

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood, but my knowledge of java is still verry limited.

Comment: @DimitriDuvanskij yes, that would get the code to compile (but whether it will do what you want it to do is another matter entirely!). Also, don't feel bad :) You're still learning!

Comment: Sorry, had to get some sleep. And indeed, it compiles but then the button does nothing.

Comment: Read both links that Lakshitha Ranasingha wrote already multiple times (read them yesterday too already) and they are not helping

Comment: And i thouth by not choosing answers i won't offend anyone. Becouse they are all doing their best to help me, feels kina rude to choose someone from all the answers (even tho some helped more then others but still)

Comment: And about improving the readability of my code: I WILL change that but first i want to complete this program. i'm working on it 12 hours a day for the last 3 days or so.... learning every day something new. Most problems I solve myself but there are still many wich I can't solve yet.

Comment: And last, can you please tell me what I have to write to make it work? (when you write the code I understand it but when i try to apply it on my own code it goes wrong all the time and gives me tons of other error messages)

Comment: @DimitriDuvanskij: Readability is not something you fix after you're done with everything else. It's something you do continuously. You don't first pick a poor misspelled miscapitalized name, and plan to fix it later. You first pick a good correctly spelled correctly capitalized name. And you indent it properly.